# Facebook API replace new line in JSON

Tags: jquery, json, facebook-graph-api

I'm using a bit of JSON to parse information from facebook pages to display on my site, which is working almost perfectly! All the information is being pulled in however I am losing the line breaks in the html (which I would like to keep).

I can see through the graph api that the new lines are displayed as `\n`, so the simplest way I can think of doing this is using jQuery to find any `\n` and replace it with `<br />` I have had a look around but a simple find and replace method such as:

```
$(span#about_" + index).html(this.html().replace('\n','<br />'));
```

However this doesn't work because the \n tags are not passed through to the html.

So I am wondering if anyone knows how I can achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My original JSON request is below:

```
$.each(json, function(index, item) {
                $(".facebook span#likes_" + index).html("<a href='" + item.link + "' alt='" + item.name + " on Facebook'><ul><li>" + item.likes + "</li></ul><h4>Facebook Fans</h4></a>");
                $("span#about_" + index).html("<p>" + item.description + "</p>");
});
```

Many thanks in advance, MB

Comment: can I see what the output of 'description' looks like?

Comment: from facebook or within my html? This information is fetched from facebook: http://pastie.org/3636417

Comment: oops, *EDITED* meant \n rather than /n!

Comment: Next time when querying IDs in the `$()` block, don't include any elements, just use `$('#about_' + index)` since it's much faster that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do `item.description.replace(/\n/g, '<br />')`?

It seems the replace method will only replace the first occurrence. If you use a regular expression you can tell it to replace globally.

```
$.each(json, function(index, item) {
    $(".facebook span#likes_" + index).html("<a href='" + item.link +
        "' alt='" + item.name + " on Facebook'><ul><li>" + item.likes +
        "</li></ul><h4>Facebook Fans</h4></a>");
    $("span#about_" + index).html("<p>" +
        item.description.replace(/\n/g, '<br />') + "</p>");
});
```

Comment: Will that go in the loop, eg:

`$.each(json, function(index, item) {
     $(".facebook span#likes_" + index).html("<a href='" + item.link + "' alt='" + item.name + " on Facebook'><ul><li>" + item.likes + "</li></ul><h4>Facebook Fans</h4></a>");
     $("span#about_" + index).html("<p>" + item.description + "</p>");
     item.description.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
});`

Sorry for the n00b question, i'm finding my feet with jQuery!

Comment: No problem - I think you can replace item.description with what I posted assuming I understand your question and code correctly :)

Comment: YES! Thanks very much amigo, you've made my site become a bit more beautiful haha.